# Thermal radiation of a nitrogen sphere

Tags: thermal-radiation, blackbody

Let's imagine a :

- sphere of 100% pure nitrogen (N2),
- (edit: 1 m diameter) with a constant volume (edit: using a kind of "magic forcefield")
- (edit : at 1 bar)
- in the void
- far from any light source (edit: background is at 0 K)
- at 300K

At this temperature, we should except any solid material to emit IR and to cool down ; it may be approximated by the dark body using an emissivity coefficient. But what happens to our N2 sphere ?

Will it cool down ? At which rate ?

(edit : Bonus question : if the sphere is at 1000K, will it glow as red iron ?)

Thanks in advance for your answer

Comment: According to you, the Nitrogen is at 300K, yeah? What is the temperature of the surroundings you've kept in? Is it absolute zero?

Comment: The sphere is in the void, and let's say that the sorrounding "observing" universe is at absolute zero.

Comment: Unless the sphere has a surface the N2 gas is gonna expand and diffuse into space

Comment: @pentane. Yes, you're right, but this is a theoretical case, for studying radiative thermal behaviour of a gas. As written by Brionius, there is a magical forcefield that keeps its shape and volume constant.

Comment: Nitrogen at 1 bar in a 1m sphere at 300K is nothing like a blackbody. It is optically thin to visible and IR radiation. You need the emission coefficient integrated over all wavelengths (which will not be $\sigma T^4$) multiplied by the (small) optical depth.

Answer (score 2):

At 300K, radiation from your ball of Nitrogen should be pretty well approximated by a black body spectrum.  The power density emitted by a black body is given by the [Stefan-Boltzmann law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stefan%E2%80%93Boltzmann_law):

$$j = \sigma T^4$$

Where $j$ is the power radiated per unit surface area.  Therefore, we'll need to know the size of your sphere.  Let's keep it general, and say it has a radius $R$, and therefore an area $A = 4 \pi R^2$. I will also assume for simplicity that this sphere of gas is confined by some kind of magic forcefield, and not worry about volume changes.  The total power radiating is therefore

$$P = A j$$
$$P = 4 \pi R^2 j$$
$$P = 4 \pi R^2 \sigma T^4$$

For a diatomic gas, the internal energy is given by $U = \frac{5}{2} N k T$.  You haven't specified how much gas is in this sphere, or the pressure, so we will again retain generality by keeping the number of particles (not moles) of gas at a constant $N$.

Now we are close to the goal of finding out how fast the sphere cools:

$$P = -\frac{dU}{dt}$$
$$4 \pi R^2 \sigma T^4 = -\frac{d}{dt} (\frac{5}{2} N k T)$$
$$4 \pi R^2 \sigma T^4 =  -\frac{5}{2} N k \frac{dT}{dt}$$
$$\frac{dT}{dt} = -\frac{8 \pi R^2 \sigma}{5 N k} T^4 $$
$$\frac{dT}{T^4} = -\frac{8 \pi R^2 \sigma}{5 N k} dt $$

Integrating...

$$- \frac{1}{3} (T^{-3} - T_0^{-3}) = -\frac{8 \pi R^2 \sigma}{5 N k} t$$
$$T^{-3} = \frac{24 \pi R^2 \sigma}{5 N k} t + T_0^{-3}$$

Finally, the temperature as a function of time for a sphere of nitrogen gas due to radiative losses is approximated by

$$T(t) = \left (\frac{1}{ \frac{24 \pi R^2 \sigma}{5 N k} t + T_0^{-3}}\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}$$

Where $T_0$ is the initial temperature, $R$ is the radius of the sphere, and $N$ is the number of particles (not moles) of gas in the sphere.

Here is a [Desmos graph of the temperature as a function of time](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/wtpqkfislr).

Here is a screenshot of the graph in case you can't use Desmos.
[image: Temperature graph]

**Caveats:**

1. This cooling function will hold until the gas becomes cool enough that rotational degrees of freedom are frozen out; then the internal energy will have a different relation to temperature.  The cooling function will have the same form, just with different constants.
2. Nitrogen gas is not a perfect blackbody - there are rotational, vibrational, and atomic resonances, but it's probably pretty close, especially at a temperature as low as 300°K.
3. This model assumes the thermal energy is lost from the entire volume uniformly, when in fact the nitrogen on the surface will lose the most.  This will result in non-uniform temperature, as well as complicated heat movement via conduction and convection that are difficult to analyze.  These effects will be smaller, and this result more accurate, if the sphere radius $R$ is small.

Comment: I've tested the expression for a 1 m sphere at 1 bar for 1 s, and it gives 1.4e-5 K. Is it an error from my calculation or do you have the same result ?

Comment: Do we need to include an emissivity for the pure N2 in the SB law ? It's difficult to find any value for N2 regarding this quantity, do you know any reference website where I may find it ?

Comment: Just a precision : I used the perfect gas law to find N=168 mol

Comment: Sorry, my mistake - I stated that "N" is the number of moles of gas, but actually the way I formulated this, it's the number of particles, so for $168~mol$, $N=10^{26}$.  I'll correct that statement in the answer.  Anyhow, for 168 mol, I get $T(1 sec) = 298.4°K$.  I also added a Desmos graph of the function.

Comment: You can't use the surface of the sphere enclosing the gas as the blackbody surface area. The gas does not radiate from that entire area-- its area is much much less than that. For example, if I was enclosing 10 gas molecules in a 1 $m^3$ sphere, do you think it would radiate as much energy as a 1 $m^3$ sphere of iron at the same temperature?

Comment: Yes, I agree that the blackbody assumption breaks down when the distance between the particles approaches the dimensions of the sphere.  But for a large number of particles, it would radiate the same amount of power as a sphere of iron at the same temperature.  Note **power**, not **energy**.  The amount of energy radiated would be much less, and the temperature would drop considerably faster.

Comment: I think it's a stretch to say the surface emission is the same as it would be for a solid. Atoms deeper inside the gas can participate in the emission since their radiation has a good probability of escape; this will affect the results in a way that I find difficult to calculate. I think you are making unsubstantiated assumptions - how the emission will vary with density is an interesting question which I don't think your answer addresses.

Comment: @ Brionius, OK, so with the Avogadro constant, I've the same result now tahn your Desmo curve, thanks.

Comment: Regarding the fact that N2 is a transparent gas on most of the spectrum, does it mean that we need to consider the problem as concentric shells ?

Comment: @Floris, that's a good point.  Probably you would need to analyze the problem as a series of concentric shells, as Hyades suggests.  I still maintain that this would be a good approximation for **small** gas spheres, as mentioned in the answer.

Comment: A 1m sphere of nitrogen at 1 bar and 300K is *nothing* like a blackbody - I'm looking *through* one right now.

Answer (score 1):

The body will lose heat according to the Stefan-Boltman law, that is the heat loss per unit surface area goes as

$$\epsilon \sigma T^4$$

where $\epsilon$ is the emissivity (which is a function of wavelength). It will be hard to judge how quickly the sphere will lose heat - but it is absolutely certain that it will lose heat, given that the surroundings are cooler and therefore heat can be lost by radiation, but not absorbed.

The fact that this is a gas and not a solid doesn't come into it: that just changes how closely the gas molecules are associated with each other; and molecules inside will radiate but they have equal probability of receiving radiation "from outside" so the next flux is still determined by the surface, that is the number of atoms "on the outside".

On further reflection it is possible that the heat loss per unit time scales with the density of the material - but then so does the heat capacity, so I think that if you do the calculation for "solid nitrogen" and scale it, you will get the right answer. Assuming you can estimate the emissivity accurately.

Comment: Is it sure that the black-body law can be used in the case of a gas ? Will the pure N2 sphere emit a black-body spectrum ? I mean that I find it hard to link the black-body assumptions (cavity) with the case of N2 sphere.

Comment: I've read on numerous website that the light from a flame comes from soot, and not from the heated atmosphere. If the N2 sphere above is at 1000 K, will it glow as red iron, as it would be if a black-body

Comment: @Hyades yes the soot particles, being more dense and more black, make good radiators. I did say that you need to take emissivity of the molecules into account - this may be quite low.